# Why did the N.I.C.E. want Mark Studdock at Belbury?

Tags: c-s-lewis, the-space-trilogy

Near the middle of **That Hideous Strength**, Wither says to the Fairy:

> If a mere arrest could have secured the — er — good will and
>   collaboration of Mrs. Studdock, we should hardly have embarrassed
>   ourselves with the presence of her husband.

This statement seems to imply that the only reason the N.I.C.E. brought Mark Studdock to Belbury was in order to get a hold of his wife, Jane. Now it turns out that Jane is a seer and an invaluable asset to either side, so the Institute wanting to get their paws on her makes perfect sense.

What doesn't make sense is that at the time Wither made that statement, the N.I.C.E. hadn't yet discovered Jane's powers. Frost had seen her in vision and was studying her in the vision—but we have no evidence that he knew it was Mark's wife that he was studying. Furthermore, Frost didn't see Jane in vision until *after* Mark was dragged to the Institute.

So, why did the N.I.C.E. want Mark Studdock at Belbury *before* they understood the significance of his wife and her gifts?

We are led to believe at various points before Wither's statement to the Fairy, that the Institute people wanted Mark so he could write good propaganda in the newspapers for them. But if that was the reason they brought him, why would Wither make that statement?

Is this a plot defect? Did the author's timing get tangled? Or am I missing something?